# When Rendering FontAwesome Icons on Android, some Icons are rendered with Overlapping Chinese Characters

Tags: android, xamarin, font-awesome, render, mvvmcross

As part of one of the views in my app, I have a place where users can choose to navigate to one of many other pages depending on which icon is tapped. To render these icons, we are using a combination of custom-designed icons and the FontAwesome icon library.

However, on some devices, such as the Samsung Galaxy S7, some of the icons do not always render as expected. In particular one of them renders in an overlapping fashion with a Chinese character. So far we have been unable to figure out why this is happening, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

We are using Xamarin Android and MvvmCross to create our app.

Some of the view code for the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/RelativeLayoutPageStyle"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/RelativeHeader"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                android:id="@+id/flag"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                style="@style/MenuButton" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Header"
                style="@style/HeaderLogo"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/TitleWithIcon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ViewFailedRecordButton"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ViewAssignmentsButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Header"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#b8860b"
                android:text="\uf06a"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                local:MvxBind="Click ViewFailedRecordsCommand;Visibility BooleanVisibility(FailedRecordsDetected)" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ViewAssignmentsButton"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="\uf022"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                local:MvxBind="Click ViewAssignmentCommand;Visibility BooleanVisibility(HaveAssignmentsForUser);TextColor AssignmentButtonColor, Converter=NativeColor" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/CollectionViewHeader"
            android:id="@+id/collectionViewHeader"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
            local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor HeaderBackgroundColor, Converter=NativeColor">
            <TextView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                style="@style/TextViewHeaderResponsive"
                local:MvxBind="Text HeaderText" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_below="@id/collectionViewHeader"
            android:layout_above="@+id/collectionViewFooter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="2" />
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/CollectionViewFooter"
            android:id="@id/collectionViewFooter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility HideOnEmptyText(FooterText);BackgroundColor FooterBackgroundColor, Converter=NativeColor;Click FooterClickCommand">
            <TextView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                style="@style/StatusBarFooterTextView"
                local:MvxBind="Text FooterText" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/Menu"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/drawerlistitem"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource NavigationCellModels" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

View for the Template used in the above GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    local:MvxBind="Click ClickCommand">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text RecordableDataTypeToIcon(RecordableDataType);Visibility IsRecordableDataTypeFontAwesome(RecordableDataType);TextColor Color, Converter=NativeColor" />
        <CbtGlyphIcon
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text RecordableDataTypeToIcon(RecordableDataType);Visibility IsRecordableDataTypeCbtGlyphValueConverter(RecordableDataType);TextColor Color, Converter=NativeColor" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        local:MvxBind="Text Title;TextColor Color, Converter=NativeColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for the FontAwesomeIcon Class:

```
public class FontAwesomeIcon : TextView
{
    private Context _context;
    protected FontAwesomeIcon(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        Initialise(null, null);
    }

    public FontAwesomeIcon(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        Initialise(context, null);
    }

    public FontAwesomeIcon(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialise(context, attrs);
    }

    public FontAwesomeIcon(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
        : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialise(context, attrs);
    }

    private void Initialise(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        _context = context ?? Application.Context;
        Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "FontAwesome.otf");
    }
}
```

Finally here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image: Chinese Character overlapping with FontAwesome Icon]

Comment: Yep - seeing this too! Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Hi!  I'm late to this party. I need to go on StackOverflow more often. I was able to solve the problem. We had icons with custom fonts that we were hiding and showing based on certain criteria. Replacing it with a label and changing which font we were using depending on condition ended up fixing the bug.

TL;DR somehow 2 icons were showing simultaneously, so the easiest thing to do was replace it with one.

Sorry for the extremely delayed response, but hopefully this gives insight to anyone else who's experienced this issue.